# Add MKAnnotation on top of UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation

I ran into a problem while building a map app. I'm trying to do the following:

- add an *animated PNG sequence* as overlay to the map so that it appears to be "on the map" while the user changing the zoom, rotation and pitch of the map.
- on top of that PNG sequence I would like to show a custom pin image, using `MKAnnotationView`.

So far, what I've been able to do is:

1. Load PNG sequence into an `UIImageView` and animate them.
2. add the `UIImageView` to the `MKMapView`, using `addSubView:`.
3. Detect changes to the `MKMapView` and update the position of `UIImageView` accordingly

However, if I start adding `MKAnnotations` to the MapView, they get added below my `UIImageView` (see image on the left).

Is there a way to add them on top of the `UIImageView` (see image on the right)?

[image: MKannotation Problem]?

Comment: If you already are monitoring map changes and updating manually, why don't you add that image as an mkoverlay instead of a subview ? As far as I know all subviews in a mapView will be placed over the annotation/overlay container.